# Is there an array-depth limitation in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json

With *array-depth*, I don't mean number of elements in an array but this construct here:

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["Too deep"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

I stumbled across this in the [test suite](http://json.org/JSON_checker/test.zip) for the [`JSON_checker`](http://json.org/JSON_checker/).

The script `pass2.json` has this (19 opening brackets):

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["Not too deep"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

As the name of the test script implies, this is expected to pass.

The other one is from `fail18.json` and is expected to fail. It has 20 opening brackets. However, [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) has not **that** much to say about Arrays:

> An array structure is a pair of square bracket tokens surrounding zero or more values. The values are
>   separated by commas. The order of the values is significant.

Is there a limit that I missed or is the test script wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already noted, the [ECMA-404 JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) does not mention any restriction on the nesting level, just that arrays/objects can nest:

> Because  objects  and  arrays can  nest,  trees  and  other  complex  data  structures  can  be  represented.
>
> A JSON value can be an *object, array, number, string,* `true`, `false`, or `null`.
>
> An array structure is a pair of square bracket tokens surrounding zero or more
> *values*.

The restriction in the test suit you refer to appears to be more a measure to set a limit to the memory usage of the program. Note the definition of the function *new_JSON_checker* in `JSON_checker.c`, one of the source files which are also available [on github](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-c). In comments the use of the *depth* parameter is explained:

> It takes a depth parameter that restricts the level of maximum nesting.

and then the code uses this argument for memory allocation:

```
jc->stack = (int*)calloc(depth, sizeof(int));
```

The range check is made elsewhere, where the comment reads:

> Return false if there is overflow.

So, in conclusion, this seems more a practical measure specific to this particular test suite.

It is clear that other parsers accept depths of much greater value: try for instance [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).